# How to update every document with a certain field in cloud firebase at once?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

hello i am trying creating a team app with flutter, cloud firebase and firebase cloud function. i want to update a field under each meamber documents that determines if it's a new month.
here is my cloud firebase structure:
[image]

[image]

as you can see i have all the workers  of a company in documents under a membership sub-collection, every document represent a worker. i want to change the field of "newMonth" to true inside every membership document every month.

i have been searching for days for a cloud function that can help me with this, here is what i got so far:

```
exports.newMonth = functions.pubsub.
schedule('* * * * *')
.onRun(async(context)=>{
    try {
        const querySnapshot =  database.collectionGroup('companies')
        .where('newMonth', '==', false).get(); 
        if ((await querySnapshot).empty){
            return null
        }else{
            const updates = [];
   
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach(snapshot =>{
                updates.push(snapshot);
                console.log('The snapshot is',snapshot);
            });
            const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(updates);
            const updates1 = [];

            snapshotArrays.forEach(snapArray =>{
                snapArray.forEach(snap =>{
                    updates1.push(snap.ref.update({
                        "newMonth" : true,
                    }))
                })
            })
           // await Promise.all(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc)=> doc.ref.update({newMonth: true})));
            console.log('succesfully changed');
            return Promise.all(updates1);
        }

        
    } catch (error) {
        functions.logger.error(error)
    }

});
```

Please can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What's the issue with using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)?

Comment: @jay i really never heard about transaction until now. and will need to research it a bit more. and i just saw that there is a limitation to update max 500 documents. is there anyway to perform the change without this limitation?

Comment: 500 is the limit - however, there may be ways to re-structure your data to make it easier. For example, if all workers have the same date stored in their node, why not store the date in a separate node and have a reference to it within each worker node. That way you can simply update one node and all the worker nodes would have access to it.

Comment: @jay i really don't understand how to clearly proceed with that, how would i manage that node? like if i say every month the value of `newMonth` is set to true, when would it be set to false? to indicate that the current day is not a new month.

Comment: I am not sure of the exact use case but in concept, if today was in the current stored month then it would be true. If today is > the current stored month, then it would be false. You could do the comparison on device or store today in the database. Or use a cloud function. The significance of "true" being stored in the worker node is not clear. We need to be careful here as database design discussions can be quite chatty and that goes beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: @jay the idea was that every month the value of `newMonth` inside every worker document would be set to true and when the user opens the app i would check if that value is true, then do something in this case set a value to 0, and then change the field of `newMonth` to false so the next time the user checks it would'nt perform any action until the value of `newMonth` is set to true again. with your approach i think the user is forced to always open the app on the first day of the month if not that value is always going to be false.

Comment: Ah. Well again, the use case was not clear. If you're just updating that field to true, why not just iterate over all the nodes and set them to true - thousands of documents will update within seconds so there doesn't appear to really be any need to update them all "at the same time"./

Comment: @jay i'm not really sure how i can do that, even tho it sounds like a good solution